# How to automatically format an SD card or a USB flash drive with one FAT32 partition that uses the entire storage space?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems, parted

I have some SD cards with some existing partitions that I want to format to one FAT32 partition and I want to do it as automatically as possible. Best just using one command.

When I connect them their existing partition gets mounted as `/dev/sdd1`.

I work on Ubuntu.

Comment: "some existing partitions" -> i.e. several => /dev/sdd1 is just one.

Comment: @Hannu True. However, the other partitions are some system partitions and don't mount automatically. If multiple of them were mounted the solution is trivially extensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The command

This command works for me:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdd1 &&\
sudo parted /dev/sdd --script -- mklabel gpt mkpart primary fat32 0% 100% &&\
sudo partprobe /dev/sdd &&\
sleep 2 &&\
sudo mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sdd1
```

#### Explanation

1. `umount /dev/sdd1` unmounts the automatically mounted partition so `parted` can delete it in the next step
2. `parted /dev/sdd` tells `parted` we want to work on the `sdd` device

   - `--script` tells `parted` to not execute in the interactive mode
   - `mklabel gpt` makes the GPT partition table on the device
   - `mkpart primary fat32 0% 100%` fills the device with the FAT32 partition (leaving it at this does not work for some reason and not doing it also does not work)
3. `partprobe /dev/sdd` tells the system to reload the device's partitions
4. `sleep 2` sleeping for some time seems to be necessary for the next command to successfully run (maybe shorter than 2 second sleep is sufficient but I want to be sure)
5. `mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sdd1` creates the FAT32 partition on `/dev/sdd1`